# Array of arrays of structs

Tags: c

I have to statically allocate a struct. It represents a row of a file.

```
typedef struct file_row {
  char lat[MAXCHAR];
  char lot[MAXCHAR];
  char noise[MAXCHAR];
} file_row_t;
```

I have to create an array of those structs so:

```
typedef file_row_t file_rows[NUMBER_OF_ROWS];
```

I have to create an array of those array of structs, so:

```
typedef file_rows array_file_row_t[NUMBER_OF_FILE];
```

To statically allocate it, I tried:

```
static file_rows file_entry_1[] = {
{ "5.83613506988462", "7.517027380149415", "17.8638534936465" }
, { "1.00316872133421", "6.081590272977937", "0.3844105125918" }
, { "4.55349057609303", "5.608649972060196", "5.9341717073556" }};
```

To statically create an array with all those files, I tried:

```
static array_file_row_t files[] = { file_entry_1, file_entry_2, file_entry_3 };
```

To get a single file entry I tried:

```
file_rows file[] = files[node_id];
```

To get a single row of this file I tried:

```
file_row_t row = file[file_pos];
```

The problem is that I got multiple errors during the compilation:
If it can helps I paste it here:

```
region_data.h:22:1: error: missing braces around initializer [-Werror=missing-braces]
{ "5.83613506988462", "7.517027380149415", "17.8638534936465" }
 ^
region_data.h:2027:35: note: (near initialization for 'file_entry_3')
region_data.h:3030:37: error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
static array_file_row_t files[] = { file_entry_1, file_entry_2, file_entry_3 };
region_data.h:3030:37: note: (near initialization for 'files[0][0][0].lat[0]')
region_data.h:3030:37: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
region_data.h:3030:37: note: (near initialization for 'files[0][0][0].lat[0]')
region_data.h:3030:51: error: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror=int-conversion]
static array_file_row_t files[] = { file_entry_1, file_entry_2, file_entry_3 };
                                               ^
```

Comment: What _is_ your question? Do you want to know what you've done wrong? Or do you want to know how to create _"Array of arrays of structs"_? Or both?

Comment: Both of them. There are conceptual errors in what I wrote and I want to understand what is wrong and how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define MAXCHAR 256
#define NUMROWS 12
#define NUMFILE 8

typedef struct row {
  char lat[MAXCHAR];
  char lot[MAXCHAR];
  char noise[MAXCHAR];
} row_t;

typedef row_t row_list_t[NUMROWS];

typedef row_list_t file_list_t[NUMFILE];

int main(void)
{
  file_list_t files;

  for(int i = 0; i < NUMFILE; ++i) {

    for(int j = 0; j < NUMROWS; ++j) {

      sprintf(files[i][j].lat, "Lat: %d", i * j);
      sprintf(files[i][j].lot, "Lot: %d", i * j);
      sprintf(files[i][j].noise, "Noise: %d", i * j);

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```c
{ file_entry_1, file_entry_2, file_entry_3 }
```

This is NOT an array of `file_rows`. This is an array of *pointers* to `file_rows`.

`file_entry_1`, `file_entry_2` and `file_entry_3` are pointers.